# How can remove onclick on firefox?

Tags: jquery, jquery-events

How can remove `onclick` on Firefox? How can do it automatically?

```
<a class="nextQuestion" onclick="loadNext();" href="javascript:void(0)" id="nextQuestion" style="opacity: 1; bottom: 10px;"></a>
```

I don't want to click it. `onclick="loadNext()`

Comment: What do you mean exactly? Do you want to remove the event after the page has loaded? Can you not just remove the attribute?

Answer (score 2):

In your particular question:

```
document.getElementById('nextQuestion').removeAttribute('onclick');
```

But, honestly, rather than adding JavaScript to the page to remove the `onclick` why not simply remove the `onclick` from the HTML source?

Or, if you really feel the need to use jQuery for this:

```
$('#nextQuestion').removeAttr('onclick');
```

Comment: i am not webmaster so i asked it for you. if i remove that code , will it work ? onclick

Comment: yeah i need it now it worked thanks :) 

$('#nextQuestion').removeAttr('onclick');